# 8 puzzle java: binary operator

Tags: java

I am building the 8 puzzle class and am a little rusty on the binary operators, and am getting a "bad operand types for binary operator '&&'".  Here is my code:

```
public boolean checkReachable(int [] goalState)
{
    int iversionCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<9 -1; i++)
        for(int j = i+1; j<9; j++)
            if(goalState[j] && goalState[i] &&  goalState[i] > goalState[j])
            {
                iversionCount++;
            }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean to check for?

Comment: Bitwise operators are nice, but I think you're better off being more readable without them.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is for booleans only.  If you want to do bitwise and, use a single `&`.

Comment: Um, a bitwise or is `|`, not `&`

Comment: @4castle:  Thanks.  I meant to say "and".  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I got confused with the logic and also left some things out.  I meant to put: if(goalState[j]!=0 && goalState[i]!=0 && goalState[i] > goalState[j])